# ODI 12c CUSTOM_TEMPLATE extract option not working

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I'm using the CUSTOM_TEMPLATE extract option on the source table to force a select actually from another table. Which then would be used by a custom IKM I'm using in order to get the column list of the "forced" table with the odiRef.getColList API. But the template select query is not considered at all in the execution, so the IKM still gets the columns from the original table and I don't need them.
The code in the CUSTOM_TEMPLATE is:

```
select *
from <%=odiRef.getObjectName("L", "#V_OFFL_TABLE_NAME", "OFFLOAD_AREA_HIST", "DWH_LCL", "D") %> 
where src_date_from_dt = to_date('V_OFFL_TRANSFER_DATE','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

The code in the SOURCE tab of the custom IKM I made is:

```
select <%=odiRef.getSrcColList("","[COL_NAME]",",\n","")%>
from <%=odiRef.getObjectName("L", "#V_OFFL_TABLE_NAME", "OFFLOAD_AREA_HIST", "DWH_LCL", "D") %> 
where src_date_from_dt = to_date('V_OFFL_TRANSFER_DATE','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

in this case I'm trying with odiRef.getSrcColList in the IKM, but I;ve also tried with odiRef.getColList - same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a Dummy Datastore in the Model where you have that table.
You can add dummy or general attributes into that Datastore(Var1,Var2,Var3...Num1,Num2..etc).
Drag this datastore to the source area and add the CUSTOM_TEMPLATE there.

**Make sure this dummy is having the same logical schema as the table in your custom query.*

This can also work with multi table query.